# Do i need to use mutableCopy to NSMutableArray when using MPMediaItem in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, mpmediaitem

Hello everyone please guide me something.

I am doing custom music app with `iPodMusicPlayer`.

Here is some of code i load songs from iPodLibrary.

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];

        MPMediaPropertyPredicate *filter = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:self.playlistName forProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonContains];

        [query addFilterPredicate:filter];      

**self.app.arrayFromAppDelegate = (NSMutableArray *)[query items];**


        self.userMediaItemCollection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:self.app.arrayFromAppDelegate];

        [self.player setQueueWithItemCollection:self.userMediaItemCollection];
```

according to above code

`self.app.arrayFromAppDelegate = (NSMutableArray *)[query items];`

**arrayFromAppDelegate** is a `NSMutableArray` that i declared in `AppDelegate`.
`[query items];` return `NSArray` and i added to `NSMutableArray` with pointer`(NSMutableArray *)`

Is that right way when i used like that?

or should i use like `self.app.arrayFromAppDelegate = [[query items] mutableCopy];`

Which way is the best for memory and do i need to use `removeAllObject` after use `mutableCopy`?

Please guide me.

sorry for my bad english.

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going from `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` don't just cast it, use the mutable copy.

Comment: so do i need to use removeAllObject after use?

Comment: If you're referring to when you release it (I use arc) you shouldn't have to.

Comment: Yes i used ARC.So i don't need to use removeAllObject?

Comment: Yea, when your mutable array gets release it will release all of the objects in the array. Now that's from a memory stand point.